# Why does rowcommand fail after pagination?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, pagination

Why does my gridview rowcommand throws error after pagination ?

i.e. I have a gridview with pagesize of 15. Each row has a button select which works until pagination i.e. after pagination the code inside rowcommand starts throwing error. Why ?

```
protected void grdViewCases_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //int index = MngOtherFunctions.CalculatedIndex(sender as GridView, Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int CaseID = Convert.ToInt32(grdViewCases.DataKeys[index % grdViewCases.PageSize].Value);
            short UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"]);

            if (e.CommandName == "cmdSelect")
            {
                HdnFieldCaseID.Value = Convert.ToString(CaseID);
                txtBoxCaseNo.Text = grdViewCases.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;

                ShowCasesByCaseID(CaseID);
                grdViewCases.Visible = true;

            }
```

this line throws error:

> Index out of range.

```
txtBoxCaseNo.Text = grdViewCases.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint into your code and check the value of index variable

Comment: @CodeNotFound 29 which is valid

Comment: check the number of rows you have at the same time

Comment: Your issue came from rows[index] with index greater thant the number of rows or Cells[1] because there is no cell à 1 index.

Comment: @CodeNotFound i tried everything but couldn't solve, any help ? 

and this should work bcz it's most needed

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `indexnot` refers to the row you select, not the page index. The value is `0`, that's why its return is out of range.

```
txtBoxCaseNo.Text = grdViewCases.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
```

In my case, I check the command sent to the method by addding

```
string _commandName = e.CommandName;
```

it will return `"Page"`, if you choose the page number